# How can I extract number from text with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract number from title. I have title like this:

**

> Apartment London, 230.400€, 450,00m2

**

I want to extract only this price number (**230.400€**), can anybody help me with this?

So far my code look like this

```
\d+\.?\d+(.)
```

Comment: `rx = /[0-9.,]+€/g;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the amount symbol as part of your RegEx:

```
/\d+\.?\d+(.)€/
```

Or you can try using Positive lookahead:

```
\d+\.?\d+(.)(?=€)
```